# parsing a string value to double with comma decimal seperator

Tags: c#, asp.net, double

if there is any one who find a solution to this

```
string x = "7,50";
string y = "5";
double a = double.Parse(x);
double b = double.Parse(y);
double c = a - b;
```

then the result must be 2,50.

but I got 70. because of decimal point x is treated as 75.

Comment: what is your current culture set to?

Comment: i am using tr-TR. I also add
double a = double.Parse(x, new CultureInfo("tr-TR"));
double a = double.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
but it did not work

Comment: @ypbr: "It did not work" isn't enough information. Please edit a short but complete program into the question, and include the output.

Answer (score 2):

Just specify the appropriate culture to `double.Parse`. For example:

```
CultureInfo french = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
double x = double.Parse("7,50", french);
```

I suspect you *actually* had "7,5" as a value, however - as "7,50" would be parsed as "750" if you were using a culture which didn't use comma as the separator.

Of course, if these are currency values you should consider using `decimal` instead of `double` to start with...

Comment: That was a master stroke!! +1

Comment: i had 7.5 as pardes value. before parsing it is 7,50 after parsing it becomes 7.5

Comment: @ypbr: It's not *at all* clear what you mean, but you need to understand that the value itself (as a `double`) doesn't have a comma or a dot - it's just a number. The format only becomes relevant when you convert it to or from a string. You haven't really given us enough information about where the data is coming from, how you're inspecting the values etc.

Comment: i simply create a string value like string a = "7,50"; and i am paring it to double. and it becomes 7.5? after that i am subtract 5 from it then the result is 70? is it not clear? and sorry for my english

Comment: If it's correctly parsing "7,50" to 7.5, then I *very* much doubt that subtracting 5 makes the answer 70. Please update your question with a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem, including specifying the culture when parsing.